# Assistance in understanding syntax

Tags: ruby, syntax

I am having trouble understanding the following:

```
@on_fallback = on_fallback || (->(_,  _){})
```

Could anybody please assist me in understanding the code that executes after the disjunciton operator?

Comment: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Procs

Comment: Thanks for the reference point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a lambda that takes two block arguments and returns `nil` when executed.

When `_` is used in an argument position of a method definition, lambda, or block, it indicates an argument that is not to be used in its scope. Unlike other argument names, `_` can appear multiple times in a scope.